# Fatal error: Cannot redeclare makenewnavurl()

Tags: php

При использовании функции выдает ошибку Fatal error: Cannot redeclare makenewnavurl() 
С чем это может быть связано?

```
function MakeNewNavUrl($arAdd)
{
   $nav_url = $GLOBALS["NAV"]["nav_filename"]."?".http_build_query(array_merge($GLOBALS["NAV"]["parsed_url"], $arAdd), '', '&amp;');
   return $nav_url;
}
```

Пример использования

```
// first page url
$arResult["NAV"]["URL"]["FIRST_PAGE"] = MakeNewNavUrl(array($arResult["NAV"]["PAGER_ID"]=>"1"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция `MakeNewNavUrl()` объявляется более одного раза.

Может беда в подключении файла с этой функцией? В таком случае вместо `include(..)` стоит воспользоваться `include_once(..)`.